# FPGA interface protocol

Tags: verilog, fpga, serial-communication

I am looking for a very fast protocol to implement interface communication between FPGAs (at the moment I am using emulated Virtex-7 FPGA).

Actually my requirements for the project I work on are really narrow. I need to transfer data in the order of gigabytes per microsecond. The data I need to transfer do not need any type of overhead computing, therefore just few signals of control are enough.
In my past, I have designed interfaces based on AXI protocol for a ZedBoard FPGA, but I am not sure it is enough. 
I am sorry if I am not totally clear for what I am looking for, but it is hard also for me figuring out this part of my project.

Answer (score 4):

Gigabytes per microsecond??  That's quite a bit... let's do some math...

I'll assume you want 2 Gigabytes per microsecond, which I think is the LEAST amount you would need based on your wording.  I'll assume for transmitting the data you're using only GPIO pins that are capable of transmitting data at 1 Gbps.  2 Gigabytes per SECOND would require 16 GPIO pins.  2 Gigabytes per MICROSECOND would require 16,000,000 GPIO Pins!  SIXTEEN MILLION PINS!

Your requirements are unobtanium.

Comment: 1 Gbps is 1 Gigabits per second. Multiply everything by 8 to get Gigabytes. More unobtanium

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Xilinx's Virtex-7 product page](http://www.xilinx.com/products/silicon-devices/fpga/virtex-7/), the Virtex-7 HT has sixteen 28Gb/s and can provide a total bandwidth of 2.78Tb/s. Converted the total bandwidth to bytes it is 347.5GB/s. Convert to bytes per microsecond and it becomes 347.5kB/us total bandwidth. **3000** Virtex-7 would be need to achieve 1 Gigabyte per microsecond. That is assuming there will be no more then 4.25% overhead added and it can maintain peek performances.

Technology has not advanced far enough to satisfy the requirements. Either relax the requirements or wait for technology to catch up. If [Moor's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law) holds true, a 16 Peta-bit per second (2 GB/us) on a single FPGA should be available by 2031.